# jQuery+AJAX response header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, cors

I am trying to read response headers using JQuery and Ajax but not all headers are returned. Only few of them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'http://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf',
    data: '',
    complete: function(resp){
        alert(resp.getAllResponseHeaders());
         }});

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tomasr/7jWSv/3/

The server response has CORS header included above, so it should be no problems accessing headers using ajax?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

I would like to read all response headers using ajax, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Is it because the ajax call is erroring?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I do not get all headers with 200 code response either http://jsfiddle.net/tomasr/7jWSv/5/

Comment: It's probably because you are doing a cross domain access which jquery does not use XHR.

Comment: @Pilot Please explain more detailed. I thought that CORS is introduced to allow cross domain request and Access-Control-Allow-Origin is used for it.

Comment: try this

`type: "GET",
async: false,
complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    var headers = XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders();
}`

Comment: @Tomas which jQuery version are you using

Comment: I use jQuery 2.1.0. I need to use POST anyway your suggested example do not work even using GET.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48572/discussion-between-pilot-and-tomas)

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by adding

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
```

to the server response and listing all headers like this

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-header-1, x-header-2, x-header-3
```

The response header above let Ajax request to read cross domain headers.